# Secure connection between django and mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django, insecure-connection

We have Django application and we are configuring `ssl` in the `DATABASES` settings in `settings.py`.

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.db.backends.mysql'
DATABASES['default']['NAME'] = 'database'
DATABASES['default']['HOST'] = "v2_host"
DATABASES['default']['USER'] = "v2_user"
DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD'] = "password"
DATABASES['default']['CONN_MAX_AGE'] = 180
DATABASES['default']['OPTIONS'] = {'init_command': 'SET SESSION wait_timeout=300',
                                     'ssl': {'cert': "/home/myuser/certpath",
                                             'key': "/home/myuser/keypath",
                                             }
                                     }
```

We are able to connect the database using this. Db team recently enforce secure/encrypted connection from client. When they enforced, we are start getting error `Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON.`

We though, passing `ssl` is secure connection. But still we are getting error. What we have to pass to make sure connection between Django and mysql are secure?

Comment: Shouldnt' you point to 'ca' in 'ssl' options? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.2/en/mysql-ssl-set.html#:~:text=5.4.82%C2%A0mysql_ssl_set()

Comment: setting `ssl_ca` will make sure it will be secure connection ?

Comment: Should be, even here they are specyfying ca https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/mysql/flexible-server/how-to-connect-tls-ssl#:~:text=crt.pem%27%7D)-,Django%20(PyMySQL),-Python